# Test if a directory has MS_NOEXEC flag set?

Tags: c, linux

I need to know if a directory is mounted with `noexec` flag, is that possible?

I found MS_NOEXEC flags [in this manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages//man2/mount.2.html), but how can I retrieve the flag in userland?

I will need to do this in C language, and reading /etc/fstab is unreliable. Does anyone know?

Comment: Read and parse `/proc/mounts`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`statvfs`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/statvfs.3.html) function and check the `ST_NOEXEC` flag.

```
struct statvfs statbuf;
statvfs("/path/to/directory", &statbuf);
if (statbuf.f_flag & ST_NOEXEC) {
    printf("Directory has the NOEXEC flag\n");
}
```

Comment: `statvfs` can fail, don't forget to check the return code